# How to create a multiple section tableview with horizontal scrolling like as below image?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader

I am trying to create a similar collection view as ![this][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wwqas.png image in tableview but i have no clue how to do it. My data is coming from server using web service.

**How to achieve this ?**

Comment: For that you can add `UICollectionView` inside `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: see this https://contentpedlar.wordpress.com/2016/10/22/uicollectionview-in-uitableview/ and https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift/

Answer (score 1):

This is seems like UICollectionView inside UITableViewCell for independent scrolling

Please go through below link for more detail...

[Click here](https://www.thorntech.com/2015/08/want-your-swift-app-to-scroll-in-two-directions-like-netflix-heres-how/)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use **UICollectionView** inside your custom **UITableViewCell**.

The flow should be like this:

```
UITableViewCell --> UICollectionView --> UICollectionViewCell
```

[image]